# Why is the cross product not the normal in this case?

Tags: matrices, vectors

I am working through the following question:

Every point **x** on a planar surface in three dimensions satisfies the relation $\bf{x}\cdot\bf{\hat{n}}=d$, where $\bf{\hat{n}}=a\bf{\hat{i}}+b\bf{\hat{j}}+c\bf{\hat{k}}$ is the unit vector normal to the plane and a,b,c,d are real constants.

(a) The position vectors $\bf{u}$, $\bf{v}$ and $\bf{w}$ such that
$\bf{u}=\bf{\hat{i}}-\bf{\hat{j}}+2\bf{\hat{k}}$, $\bf{v}=3\bf{\hat{i}}-\bf{\hat{j}}+\bf{\hat{k}}$, $\bf{w}=2\bf{\hat{i}}+\bf{\hat{j}}-\bf{\hat{k}}$ all lie on the plane. Find the components of the unit normal $\bf{\hat{n}}$ and d.

I understand that a solution to this problem can be found by solving
$[1,-1,2;3,-1,1;2,1,-1]\cdot[a,b,c]^T=[d,d,d]^T$.

What I don't understand is why the cross product between any two of the vectors $\bf{u}$, $\bf{v}$ and $\bf{w}$ don't give you the normal to the plane and hence why the solution isn't simply $\bf{\hat{n}}=\frac{\bf{u} \ \times \ \bf{v}}{|\bf{u} \ \times \ \bf{v}|}$.

Could somebody please explain why my reasoning with the cross product is incorrect? Many thanks.

Comment: u, v, and w don't all lie in the same plane. (proof: any linear combination of v and w have their y and z components equal and opposite, but u doesn't) Are you sure you have the numbers correct? Also, use \times for the cross product symbol.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Thanks for your response - I am sure that the numbers are correct, must be the question that has it wrong. The solution involves solving the matrix equation I wrote out for solutions to a,b,c and d. If the vectors arent all in plane, do you know why the matrix equation has a solution?

Comment: The plane presumably does not pass through the origin. A point on the plane (written as a displacement vector from the origin) is therefore not parallel to the plane.

Comment: Any three points lie on at least one plane. More than one if they are colinear, but always at least one. What are you trying to say, @eyeballfrog ?

Comment: $n=(u-w)\times (v-w)$ will work, if the points are not colinear. But $n$ is not supposed to be normal to $u,v,w.$ It is normal to the plane.

Comment: Oh right, I was thinking of the vectors lying in a plane, not the points. Normally I would use ordered triples for points rather than vectors.

Comment: It's too bad that we use identical language and symbols for vectors that specify a position and vectors that specify a direction.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you for your answer - this solves my mistake. I made the same assumption as eyeballfrog and thought that the vectors all lie in the plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbf n$ is normal to the plane. You’ve found instead a vector normal to $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v.$ But that obviously can’t work, because then $\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf u=0.$

A hint at what is wrong with your $\mathbf n$ is that it doesn’t depend on $\mathbf w.$

Your $\mathbf n$ would work if $d=0,$ which is equivalent to the plane including the zero vector.

You *can* use the cross product to find $\mathbf n.$ You can choose $$\mathbf n=\frac{(\mathbf u-\mathbf w)\times (\mathbf v-\mathbf w)}{\| (\mathbf u-\mathbf w)\times (\mathbf v-\mathbf w)\|}.$$ This works if $\mathbf u,\mathbf v,\mathbf w$ are not colinear.

Essentially, $\mathbf n$ has to be normal to $\mathbf u-\mathbf v,\mathbf v-\mathbf w,$ and $\mathbf w-\mathbf u.$